# How to explode an array_agg

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have a data:

```
$data = '{123, 456, 231, 478, 123, 673}'; //This is a string. I used "array_agg" in SQL.

$value = explode("," , $data);
```

The problem with this is that I obtain something like this:

```
$value[0] = '{123';
$value[1] = '456';
.
.
$value[5] = '673}';
```

How can I get the exact value I want? I want to remove the '{}'. Thanks!

Comment: `$value = explode("," , trim($data, '{}'));`

Answer (score 0):

use str_replace to remove '{'

like

```
$data = '{123, 456, 231, 478, 123, 673}';
$data=str_replace('{',"",$data);
$data=str_replace('}',"",$data);
```

Comment: Maybe a tiny bit quicker to do `$data=substr($data,1,-1);` to just remove first/last character

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the chars, you don't want with str_replace first.

```
$data = str_replace(['{', ' '], '', $data);
```

Also it looks a little bit like `JSON`. In this case you can go with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php) instead of `explode`.

```
$data = '[123, 456, 231, 478, 123, 673]';
$value = json_decode($data, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of methods to remove the `{` and `}` characters. But if they're always going to be the first and last character, this would be a fast method:

```
$data = '{123, 456, 231, 478, 123, 673}';
$data = substr($data,1,-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove braces use below code,

```
$value = explode("," ,  substr($data, 1, -1));
```

to get the value you want you have to form an array like this,

```
$value = array('123'=>'123','456'=>'456',....);
```

so that you can pass your desired value as key and get your value,

```
$value['123'] gives you '123'
```